# SQL Server multi rows query with group by

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

i have data like

```
╔══════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ DEPT ║ EMPLOYEE ║ IMAGE ║
╠══════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║    1 ║        1 ║ Y     ║
║    1 ║        2 ║ N     ║
║    2 ║        3 ║ N     ║
║    2 ║        4 ║ N     ║
╚══════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

from a query **i want to get only departments with  images = 'N'**

so this **should return dept 2**

how will i do that in SQL Server Select statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Dept
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY DEPT
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [Image] = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a92f0/2)

Comment: Good eye @JW.  perhaps the OP could have said "I want to get departments where all the image values are 'N'"

Comment: @RalphShillington the question is unclear. I just based my answer on the result. hehe

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Distinct Dept from TableName where Image = 'Y'
```

But your example will bring back Dept 1 AND Dept 2, because your 2nd record for Dept 1 has a value of 'N' under Image.  You won't just get back dept 2.